# MonoMac Exceptions Not Bubbling Up‏

Tags: c#, exception, monomac

I'm relatively new to MonoMac, and I'm having a problem handling exceptions that are thrown from a referenced assembly. I'm building my GUI on OS X 10.7 (MonoMac 2.10, MonoDevelop 3.1, Xcode 4.3), and I'm referencing a .NET 4.5 assembly I built on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012. The library is completely compatible with Mono: no flags at all are raised when I run it through MoMA. The problem is this: if an exception is thrown in the library, the GUI hangs, even in debug mode. There's no exception handling in the class library: the try/catch statements are around the calls in the GUI, but the exception never gets there. If I test the same failed method in a console app in Windows, the exception bubbles up correctly. Has anybody experienced this, or have any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Er, um, heh heh. My bad: it was how I had configured the debug settings in MonoDevelop -- I had everything turned on, so my basic exceptions were getting lost in the mix. Sorry about that. Thanks.